# How to update Google Play Developer API on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Hi i have flutter app and uploaded on googleplay, my google play console show a warning :

> We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google
>   Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API
>   will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.

how to fix this ?

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239], locale en-ID)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Flutter plugin used in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flare_flutter: ^1.5.0
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  shimmer: ^0.0.6
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.4
  flutter_cache_manager: ^0.3.2
  cached_network_image: ^0.8.0
  sqflite: ^1.1.5
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
  intl: ^0.15.7
  badges: ^0.0.6
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  google_maps_flutter:  0.0.3+3
  photo_view: ^0.4.0
  rounded_modal: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: 4.1.0+1
  cupertino_range_slider: ^1.0.1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
  package_info: 0.3.2+1
  easy_listview: ^0.1.3
  flutrans: ^0.0.2
```

Comment: I would go through each plugin used to see which ones use the Google Play API and checking for the latest version. For example you are using `google_maps_flutter:  0.0.3+3` while the plugin is at [0.5.19+2](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#-changelog-tab-). There may be others

Comment: my problem is i didnt want upgrade to androidX, so use google_maps_flutter 0.0.3+3

Comment: You might want to update your plugins then to get past that error.